# Geometric significance of an integral.

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

What is the geometric significance of the following integral?  $$\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{ti}dt$$

First of all: What am I integrating over? The result ought to be $2i$ - how does that fit in?

Comment: Integrating around the unit circle clockwise for a half turn.

Comment: You mean area of of that half-circle? I am completely lost here...

Comment: Well it is a contour integral I think, not finding an area specifically. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration#Contour_integrals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curve $C$ described by $z:t\in[0,\pi] \mapsto z(t)=-ie^{it}$ has the curve element $dz = z'(t) dt = e^{it} dt$. Therefore, you can consider your integral as $\int_C d z = z_\pi - z_0$ where $z_0 = -ie^{i0} = -i$ is the start point of the curve and $z_\pi = -i e^{i\pi} = i$ is the end point of the curve. As you see you get $\int_C dz = 2i$.